# How can I delete Streaming API Push Topics in salesforce?

Tags: streaming-api

I have created a push topic in salesforce now i want to delete/deactivate this pushtopic. For doing so i require push topic id. I am not able to figure out how can i get ID for a given pushtopic

can any body help me with the same

Answer (score 8):

Open Developer Console by clicking your name up top-right:

[image: developer console]

Go to Debug > Execute Anonymous:

[image: execute anonymous]

Then select your PushTopic(s) by name and delete them:

```
List<PushTopic> pts = [SELECT Id FROM PushTopic WHERE Name = 'Channel'];
Database.delete(pts);
```

Answer (score 6):

Go to [workbench](https://workbench.developerforce.com) ,login with your salesforce credentials.

Select queries -> Streaming Push Topics -> select your push topic and click on delete button

Comment: As of Feb 8, 2017, the only buttons are Subscribe / Unsubscribe / Details / Show Polling and Clear.  There is no longer a delete button.

Comment: The delete button is shown once you click _Details_.

Answer (score 1):

If you have created the PushTopic in apex, you will get the Id of the topic from the sobject instance after insertion. If you have not used apex for creation of the push topic, you can query the PushTopic object with Name and get the Id of the topic.

```
SELECT Id, Name FROM PushTopic WHERE Name='myTopic'
```

Comment: It maybe worth enhancing your answer with the SOQL statement showing querying PushTopic by Name and selecting Id.